# How search engines works with LARAVEL routes for SEO

Tags: php, laravel, seo

I have created a couple of routes on LARAVEL to use on a web project, for example a have in LARAVEL: "/books/{title}" i think for example that in a web browser it will looks like "http://www.example.com/books/red-river-history", but i don't understand how will works when a user search in Google a book like "Nice Red Car" and match that search with my route on my project, i mean, how it will use the words to match with "/books/{title}", i'm newbie in this, thank you so much...

Comment: Normally what you would do is create a separate file and name it sitemap.php in your views then you can write codes in your sitemap file that autoloader every book as a urlset. You can check for the standard way to build sitemaps. Then you create a route that ends with .xml pointing to your sitemap.php A Controller is needed too. Then in your controller function for adding books after successfully adding a new book use curl library to resubmit your sitemap.

Comment: On the example of "bookstore", the "title" of the book it needs to be saved on Data base with "-" for example "The-Code-DaVinci"? , i mean, because the XML sitemap file will contain the url "http://www.samplesite.com/books/the-code-davinci", this is correct?

Comment: Don't store the title as a valid url slug instead Create a new column `slug` in your database table and store valid URL's there, reference it(the new slug column) in your sitemap file. That should do!